# Constructor with by-value parameter & noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

In this example code:

```
explicit MyClass(std::wstring text) noexcept;
```

Is the use of `noexcept` here correct? `wstring` can potentially throw on construction but does the throw happen before we are in the constructor or while we are in the constructor?

EDIT: Suppose this can be generalised to any function taking a by-value parameter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The construction and destruction of function parameters happens in the context of the caller. So no, if the construction of `text` throws, that is not a violation of `noexcept`.

Soon folks would comment and ask for a spec quote :) So I will give you 5.2.2p4

> The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
>   calling function.